# New Timeline look landing tab / page

Tags: tabs, facebook-page

Is there any way to create a default landing tab / page for Facebook apps? Since publishing to the new Look / Timeline, this option has disappeared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no more default landing tab with timeline - it has been removed. I'm not sure where FB has documented this, but it listed in several popular media sources.

[6 changes coming from brand timeline - lujure.com](http://blog.lujure.com/2012/02/29/new-facebook-fan-page-timelines-changes/)

[Vitrue blog post](http://www.vitrue.com/timeline-for-brands-your-facebook-makeover-starts-today/) mentioned at the bottom

Comment: Thanks @covati! Do you / does anyone know if there's an effective way to encourage users to click on the application / Like the application since we've now lost this landing page functionality?

Comment: You could try utilizing the cover photo or "highlight" a post that asks people to like your page.

Comment: Oh, BTW, I should mention that there are very strict limitation on the cover photo: http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=276329115767498

Comment: Thanks @covati, I was just about to put a call to action in the cover, but it seems this isn't allowed!